# meaning of inline const char * operator*(AnEnumClass aclassinstance)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

What is the meaning of the following?

```
inline const char * operator*(AnEnumClass aclassinstance) {
    ...
}
```

Is it a function call operator overloading of the '*' operator or of the '()' operator?
What does it accomplish and what is it used for?

Comment: `operator()()` is an overload of the `()` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inline  // function should be marked as inline.
const char *  // function returns this
operator *  // function is the multiplication operator
(AnEnumClass aClassInstance)  // RHS argument to operator
```

The operator takes as LHS whatever the encapsulating class is.

You invoke it with:

```
const char * aString = aClass * aEnum;
```

(Given instances of the encapsulating class and the enumeration type.)

Both Wikipedia and cppreference.com have a whole page on operator precedence and argumentation that you should peruse.

Answer (score 0):

It's an overload of the `*` operator that is returning a `const char *`.